# Laravel Many-To-Many relation returns no results

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am currently learning Laravel and I have an issue which I can't seem to find a solution for. I have a many-to-many relation between two tables that always returns nothing. Let me show you the basic setup:

My posts Model:

```
// App\Post.php
protected $fillable = [
    'name',
    'description'
    'videopath'
];

public function Tags()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag');
}
public function Cats()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Cat');
}
```

My tags model:

```
// App\Tag.php
protected $fillable = [
    'name',
    'description'
];

public function exercises()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Exercise');
}
```

My posts controller:

```
// PostController.php
public function show($id)
{
    $post = Post::find($id);
    return view('posts', ['post'=>$post];
}
```

The view:

```
// posts.blade.php
@foreach($post->tags() as $tag)
    //do stuff
@endforeach
```

The intermediate table is called `post_tag` and contains the `post_id` and `tag_id` columns. At first it returned the results as expected but after some while all of my posts didn't return any tags anymore. The cats model looks similar to the tags model. Anyone has an idea?

Comment: Try this: `@foreach($post->Tags as $tag)`

Comment: Kindly use lower case function names such as `tags` & `cats`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Check the name of your Tags function. In your view you are calling "**tags**" instead of "**Tags**".
2. Have you created the intermediate table in your database? If so, check the naming convention (alphabetic order) that Laravel uses to find it: in your case it should be `tag_post`. if not, [customize the name of the table when defining the relationship.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

> ### Many To Many
>
> Many-to-many relations are slightly more complicated than hasOne and hasMany relationships. An example of such a
>   relationship is a user with many roles, where the roles are also
>   shared by other users. For example, many users may have the role of
>   "Admin". To define this relationship, three database tables are
>   needed: `users`, `roles`, and `role_user`. The `role_user` table is derived from the alphabetical order of the related model names, and contains the `user_id` and  `role_id` columns.

Comment: It was actually that I was missing an intermediate table. Wow. That was stupid from me. Thank you very much.

Comment: @NurullahYel glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Taking your view:

```
@foreach($post->tags() as $tag)
    //do stuff
@endforeach
```

`$post->tags()` will return the relationship instead of the actual collection. You want `$post->tags` instead or `$post->tags()->get()`.